# Velocity Template Language: subtract two variables

Tags: java, xml, vtl

I am new to VTL and have been trying to subtract a variable from a constant. I am sending an integer InstanceId from the back-end as a part of InstId object. I am using VTL as an XML parser. So the input to the parser is like:

```
<InstId>
  <InstanceId>4098</InstanceId>
</InstId>

!Velocity Code
#set ($start_constant = 3995)
#set ($instanceId = $InstId.InstanceId.TEXT_ )    
#set ($DomainTag = $instanceId - $start_constant)    
!DomainTag Value: $DomainTag
!DomainTag Value: $DomainTag.TEXT_
```

I tried to print the values using the above two debug statement but, It doesn't print anything. What am I missing?

I am subtracting the variables, in the same way, as stated in [this](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html) user guide.

Regards,
Shivam

Comment: What type is `$InstId.InstanceId.TEXT_`?

Comment: It's an Integer, I am using Java in the back-end.